# How to integrate Hybris with SAP Identity Management?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, netweaver, sap-business-technology-platform

I already found some useful documentation about integrating Hybris with **SAP Cloud Platform Identity Authentication** in here https://help.sap.com/viewer/50c996852b32456c96d3161a95544cdb/1905/en-US/de5382b859aa437da1b0428555169a35.html

But what I need to do and was not able to find is how to integrate Hybris with  **SAP Identity Management**(https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_IDENTITY_MANAGEMENT/8.0/en-US)

Is there someone who knows how  can this be done and what OOTB extensions are needed in order to achieve this ?